# executing a Unix utility from Python

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I have a Unix utility, which is called `hex2bin` which gets a hex file and generates a bin file. I have a python code that generates the hex file and I want my python code after generating the hex file to call this `hex2bin` utility, which if I call in a terminal in Unix I call as:

```
hex2bin input_file.hex output_file.bin
```

I did some search and and based on my findings I tried something like:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['hex2bin', input_file.hex, output_file.bin],
                            stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr = subprocess.PIPE
                        )

(out, err) = proc.communicate()
print(out)
```

but I get an error as:

```
NameError: name 'input_file.hex' is not defined
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: You haven't quoted `input_file.hex` or `output_file.bin`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Use `subprocess.run` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).

Comment: This should be reopened, as there are ways to improve on and simplify the solution, even if there was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call("hex2bin input_file.hex output_file.bin", shell=True)
```

This should simplify a lot of the actions that you're trying to perform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although it was true that there was a typo in the original question, but your answer is much nicer and simpler and I accepted that.